# table in chrome keeps collapsing when cells have no content?

Tags: html, css, html-table, tablecell

### css

```
html,body{height:100%}
.mwh{width:100%;height:100%}
.w75c{width:75%}
.bor,.bor td,.bor th{border:1px teal dashed}
```

### htm

```
<table class="mwh bor">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### The Problem

When the table has the `bor` class the 1st and 3rd cells display thier respective 12.5% width, yet when the `bor` class is removed both side cells collapse unless their is content within them like `<td>&nbsp;</td>`.

is there a way to have it so as these side cells do not collapse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

`table-layout: fixed;`

to the table css. You will not need the fixed width then.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/812/

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height:100%
}
.mwh {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    table-layout:fixed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
td {width:30%}
```

```css
html,body{height:100%}
.mwh{width:100%;height:100%}
.w75c{width:75%}
.bor,.bor td,.bor th{border:1px teal dashed}
td {width:30%}
```

```html
<table class="mwh bor">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: want to avoid it if possible due to mulit-nested table elements

Comment: use the css like, mwh>tr>td {width:30%} It only targets the immediate children.

Comment: agreed but should the content of the central cell change then the sides will be stuck at 30% whereas i need somethin like `td{margin:auto;}` to ensure a smooth look